# AVPlayer takes lot of time to start playing song from url

Tags: swift, avplayer, avplayeritem

im new to swift development.Im working on a music player app.

Im using AVPlayer to stream music from url. It is playing music fine.But it takes a lot of time to start playing. I searched a lot and none of the solutions worked for me. im adding the code im using below.

```
 func playMusic(){
     player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)
    let url = NSURL(string: musicURL )
    playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url! as URL)
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem!)
    playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)


             if player?.rate != nil{

                player?.play()
               // player?.playImmediately(atRate: 1.0)
                player?.volume = 1.0
                isPlayingDownloadedSong = false
                didAVStreamingPlayerPlayedOnce = true
                isSongLoading = true
                //to get duration only once
                didGetDurationOfCurrentSong = false
                didGetDuration = false 
        self.startLoader()
       musicObserver.playerTimeObserver()
        self.didLoaderTurnedOff = false

        // this is for player page
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "startLoader"), object: nil)

         NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidFinishPlaying(note:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: playerItem)

                let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

                do {


                    try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
                }
                catch{

                    print("some error happened")
                }

                self.playBtnInMusicPlayer.setImage( imageLiteral(resourceName: "pause"), for: .normal)

                self.musicNameLabelInMusicPlayer.text = songName

            }

    }
```

i have added the both these codes.

```
automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = false   
automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = true


  player?.playImmediately(atRate: 1.0)
```

tried both of the above lines

But none of them works for me . Please help me with this

Comment: this value `automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling` set true or false ?

Comment: i mean ,i tried both of them @a.masri

Comment: automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling should be false for less buffering time.

Answer (score 0):

Do check if you are in a network where scanning is enabled. if yes, try whitelisting the play url.

Note: The above should be a comment but reputation matters :|

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i did not understand any of your terms. How Can i do all those u tried. >

Comment: i meant the network you are using. If it is a company/institution network you are using try playback in a cell/mobile network maybe.